# is there any way to quantify what an increase of X does in variance?

Tags: inference

I am working with a data set that deals with performance related metrics and their impact on revenue. I was able to show via regression modelling and time series analysis that there is evidence of these metrics leading to an increase in revenue.

One of the questions I have been asked to explore is the effect of performance variance. For example, if we were to reduce variance by X amount, how would that impact revenue?

I'm not sure how to go about this. Is there a better way of doing this than bucketing the variance as a categorical variable into a model explaining revenue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to assume that the correlation would stay the same despite a reduction in variance (likely not going to happen, see any research on range restriction) you could alter a derivation of the formula for beta and input a reduced variance in place of the current variance. So basically if you take
SD<sub>performance</sub>SD<sub>revenue</sub>r<sub>per rev</sub> / Var<sub>revenue</sub>. You can alter the SD<sub>performance</sub> by whatever you want the reduction to be.

If you don't need to quantify it the answer is much simpler. Reducing variance reduces the relationship. As a variable becomes more of a constant (no variance) its relationships with other variables is reduced.